# In WP versions >= 4.0, is FORCE_SSL_LOGIN forcing HTTPS for the entire admin session?

Tags: ssl, https

If I'm not mistaken, I recall being able to use `FORCE_SSL_LOGIN` to secure just the WP login process and not the entire admin session, which is the purpose of `FORCE_SSL_ADMIN`. Some browsers would keep HTTPS in the URL after login, but switching to HTTP would not redirect back to HTTPS.

I have WP 4.0 and 4.1 installations, and I'm using the `FORCE_SSL_LOGIN` define in my wp-config.php, but any attempt to use HTTP during an admin session is redirected back to HTTPS.

I haven't looked at the source code for this process prior to experiencing this issue, but to me it seems `FORCE_SSL_LOGIN` and `FORCE_SSL_ADMIN` will result in the same experience, HTTPS for the entire admin session.

Looking at `wp_ssl_constants()` in wp-includes/default-constants.php, I see `force_ssl_admin(true)` is called, if `FORCE_SSL_LOGIN` is defined and true. Also, wp-admin/admin.php calls `auth_redirect()` (see wp-includes\pluggable.php) and `auth_redirect()` uses `force_ssl_admin()` and seems to redirect to HTTPS if `FORCE_SSL_LOGIN` is true and the current request is using HTTP and the request URL contains "wp-admin".

Has anyone else experienced this behavior? Am I understanding the code correctly?

Answer (score 1):

`FORCE_SSL_LOGIN` is marked as deprecated since 4.0 in source (you might have jumped over that bit). So it does now force all of admin to SSL and past behavior for it seems to no longer be available.

Comment: Well, I saw the deprecated comment but wasn't exactly sure it being deprecated would alter the behavior. I guess it does.